# Web deploy with MSBuild deploys only BIN folder

Tags: asp.net, msbuild, web-deployment

I have a website project (not a web application) and I want to set up deployment after builds with TFS. I have set this up and got it to work. I set up the build agent machine and the server and also created a publish settings file for the website project.

I know that the publishing agent is communicating with the IIS management service and that all permissions are set correctly, since after a build MSBuild does deploy the `bin` folder to the target. What I don't understand is why the rest of the website is not copied as well.

I run MSBuild with the following arguments:
`/p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True /p:PublishProfile=QA /p:VisualStudioVersion=12.0 /p:UserName=[my AD user name] /p:Password=[my AD password]`

I know these settings are correct, since the `bin` folder does get published, but how do I get the rest of the website project to publish as well?

Comment: Can you try with these additional msbuild properties? `/p:UseWPP_CopyWebApplication=true` and `/p:PipelineDependsOnBuild=false`? This enables the new publishing targets (the same ones you use when publishing from Visual Studio).

Comment: @julealgon - Thanks for the comment. Same thing with the suggested parameters added.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with the "rest of the website".  Typically all your website assets are compiled into binaries and deployed like that.

If you wish to deploy additional files you can do this in the publish settings in your project properties:

[image]

Comment: I mean CSS files, JS files, Images, ASPX files, etc. I'm publishing a web site, not just the assemblies built by MSBuild.

Comment: And also, this properties page is available for web applications, not website projects.

Comment: Oh, if you're using Website projects my advice is to STOP.  Use Web Application projects.

Comment: You`re preaching to the choir :) This is a project that has been running for several years, in a very conservative organization. They are basiclly afraid that since all code-behind files are compiled in to a single assembly, any change will call for a regression test of everything. Like any religious belief, it's almost impossible to make a compelling case against it. So I choose my battles.